# Trying to get a list value as return value with to-report

Tags: list, return-value, netlogo

I want to get a certain value out of a list with report. I try to do it with the following code:

```
to go
   print get-list [3]
end

to-report get-list [val]
  let list-name [1 2 3 4 5 6]
  report item val list-name
end
```

However, I get the following error message "ITEM expected input to be a number but got the list [3] instead."

Comment: Do not put brackets around function arguments.

Comment: Thanks. Can you put it as answer? Then I can give you an upvote.
But really, sometimes the devil is in the details

Comment: @Hannah, you should upvote *and* accept the answer, so your question stops showing up as an "unanswered" question.

Comment: I can't. Because this is a comment and not written as an answer. That's what I meant in my previous comment

Comment: @Hannah I agree that answers should not be in comments, so OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User-defined procedures declare their parameters in brackets, but (as with builtin NetLogo primitives) we do not put brackets around the arguments when using these procedures.  So you want `print get-list 3` instead of `print get-list [3]`.

By the way, when you declare `to-report get-list [val]`, that rules out using `val` as a global.  (NetLogo does not allow local identifiers to shadow global identifiers.)  I therefore recommend adopting a convention of prepending a particular symbol of your choice to procedure parameters.  My preference is the octothorpe, so the procedure header becomes `to-report get-list [#val]`.  This is definitely *not* a standard NetLogo convention, but nevertheless, I recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

or for a quick fix,

```
print get-list item 0 [3]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.